# Activate window only if it's on the current workspace

Tags: unity, workspaces

I use Unity Desktop Environment and have multiple workspaces enabled.

Several windows are open (some are minimized to the launcher) and spread across my workspaces. Now I would like to be able to focus a window *only if it's on my current workspace*, otherwise nothing should happen.

> **Example:**
>
> - Workspace 1: Firefox, Thunderbird
> - Workspace 2: gedit, LibreOffice Writer
> - Workspace 3: QTox
>
> If my active workspace is 1, I want to find a way that allows me to only focus either Firefox or Thunderbird, but not to accidentally focus any window on other workspaces and automatically switch to that workspace.

I want to be able to use *both mouse and keyboard* to switch windows this way.
How can I do this most easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy, you don't even have to set up anything!

### Using the keyboard:

To switch between windows on the current workspace only, **use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>**.
<sub>If you wanted to switch between windows on all workspaces instead, you would have used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> instead.</sub>

### Using the mouse:

<sup>Normally you would left-click on the launcher icons to focus an already opened window on any workspace.</sup>
But to only focus windows on the current workspace instead, don't click its icon with the left mouse button, but **move the mouse wheel up or down when pointing at its icon with the mouse cursor**.

Comment: Shouldn't you be accepting your own answer???  Or do you disagree with yourself??? **;-) :P**

Comment: @Fabby I should, but because of the 2-days-delay to accept own answers, I forgot about that one. Thanks for reminding! :D

Comment: That's what I figured and why you got the friendly reminder!  **;-)**